# Deploy Java application using Bluemix Liberty for Java

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

We are trying to deploy a spring-based Java application to Bluemix using the Liberty for Java buildpack. We see the error below. We are not even using the org.apache.tiles package. The same application build works fine on a development Tomcat server.

```js
Stack Dump = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.tiles.el.ScopeELResolver

        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)

        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)

        at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.MethodMap.getMethods(MethodMap.java:150

)

        at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.MethodMap.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodM

ap.java:86)

        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.getAllDeclaredMe

thods(InjectionProcessorManager.java:430)

        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.processAnnotatio

ns(InjectionProcessorManager.java:231)

        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMe

taData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:514)

        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.OSGiInjectionEngineImpl.proc

essInjectionMetaData(OSGiInjectionEngineImpl.java:239)

        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.processImpl(Reference

ContextImpl.java:633)

        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceCont

extImpl.java:305)

        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.OSGiReferenceContextImpl.pro

o

cess(OSGiReferenceContextImpl.java:31)

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationStart(

WebApp.java:254)

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1038)

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6565)

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVi

rtualHost.java:468)

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(D

ynamicVirtualHost.java:463)

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebCont

ainer.java:1051)

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$000(WebContainer.jav

a:104)

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$2.run(WebContainer.java:870

)

        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.el.ScopeELResolver

        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibrar

yClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)

        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoa

der.java:282)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadCla

ss(AppClassLoader.java:477)
```

Comment: It looks like this is failing during annotation scanning. Are there warnings in the messages log that annotation scanning has failed for a specific class? Something like [WARNING ] CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver?

Comment: Does the app work okay using the java_buildpack (tomcat)?
`cf push myapp -p myapp.war -b java_buildpack`

Comment: I think that here there is a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580808/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-tiles-tilesapplicationcontext

Comment: @Ramesh Kumar R, Were you able to fix the problem? Am running into similar issue and I dont use Tiles package either. Could you pls help?